# Error when installing Spacy using PIP - exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, spacy

I am trying to install SpaCy in Anaconda prompt for Python 3.7.3 and getting error below.

I have upgraded pip (to 19.3.1) and setuptools (to 41.6.0) to latest version.

I need to use proxy and dont have (local) admin rights, so I can not setup virtual environmen.

Any ideas what may help ? I am newby. Thank you!!

```
(base) C:\>python -m pip install --proxy INT%5Cuser:password@proxy:port spacy
Collecting spacy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/e2/81233a60e63fa94bfbddbe2c0902d1c50d80ef33666630683e9b2486f501/spacy-2.2.2.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\u213356\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3epvxcgn\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools
       cwd: None
  Complete output (7 lines):
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03ED00B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03ED0430>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03ED0230>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03ED0C50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03ED09B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\u213356\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-3epvxcgn\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was caused by Anaconda being 32bit whereas the OS was 64 bit. Reinstalled 64 bit version of Anaconda and everything is working smoothly.